# iptables NAT issue with connections involving RST packets

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, nat

I have a setup that resembles something like the following.

Application > Local Server > VPN > Remote VPN Server > License Server

The application and local server are on my LAN. The local server connects via a VPN to the corporate VPN server, which is how the local server can see the corporate license server.

I tell my application to find a license at my local server and add the following iptables rules to my local server.

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

licServer=$(host licserver | awk '/has address/ { print $4 ; exit }')
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1642 -j DNAT --to-destination $licServer:1642
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 57109 -j DNAT --to-destination $licServer:57109

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

This seems to work and the application will successfully acquire a license. However, the negotiation is very slow compared to a local session (that doesn't use my rules).

If I look at wireshark, I see that the application is sending some unusual messages. No FIN packets are ever sent, instead the application sends RST packets. I notice every time it sends one of these RST packets, there is an almost exact 10 second wait before it sends the next message. I don't think this is a coincidence, seeing as the CLOSE_WAIT timeout is 10 seconds.

A typical negotiation would start something like the following

```
t=0 Application:A > Local Server:1642 [SYN]
t+0.1 Local Server:1642 > Application:A [SYN, ACK]
t+0.1 Application:A > Local Server:1642 [ACK]
t+0.1 Application:A > Local Server:1642 [PSH, ACK]
t+0.2 Local Server:1642 > Application:A [PSH, ACK]
t+0.2 Application:A > Local Server:1642 [RST, ACK]   (10 second wait here)
t+10.2 Application:B > Local Server:57109 [SYN]
```

... and so on. Whenever there is a RST, it waits another 10 seconds.

When the application is local to the license server, the same messages are sent, but there is no 10 second wait after sending the [RST, ACK] packet.

My question is therefore, what is NAT doing on my server that could cause my application to hang for 10 seconds after sending an RST packet?

Comment: If it makes a difference, I just checked wireshark on the local server, and it appears the [RST, ACK] packet is being accepted at the local server and forwarded through the VPN tunnel to the license server.

Comment: another update: `netstat-nat -n` on the server shows the offending socket in the CLOSE state. Immediately after this entry is purged from the table the negotiation resumes. I'm even more confident this has something to do with the kernel holding the connection open after seeing RST.

Comment: I tried changing the value in `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close` to 0, 1 & 20 and whilst this does directly influence how long `CLOSE` connections hang around according to `netstat-nat -n` it makes no difference at all to the license negotiation, with [RST] packets still being followed by a 10 second delay

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it turns out the issue was totally unrelated to NAT.

The license server was sending its own hostname as part of the payload of a prior packet. Obviously this hostname was uncontactable by the application, so the 10 seconds comes from some timeout in the application. My guess is it tries the hostname, then after 10 seconds, tries the first address it had (that's how it ultimately works).

Once I added the hostname of the license server to the hosts file on the client machine it works.

I feel like a royal idiot. Thanks all that looked.